# GRPC for android fails on check for SO_REUSEPORT

Tags: android, grpc

We are considering to use grpc as a means of communicating between processes on the same computer. Now we're testing if it supports Android. We compiled "hello world" test programs from the grpc source, and were able to run on an Android device (4.0.4). However, the test failed with the following output:

E0915 13:23:11.914287843    1074 tcp_server_posix.c:150]     check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1473945791.913738526","description":"OS Error","errno":92,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.c","file_line":181,"os_error":"Protocol not available","syscall":"setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT)"}
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051

Is this possible to fix somehow? Or does it simply mean that we can't use grpc on Android?

Trying to set the options manually:

```
class Opts : public ::grpc::ServerBuilderOption
{
 public:
  void UpdateArguments(ChannelArguments* arg) GRPC_OVERRIDE
  {
      std::cout << "UpdateArguments called:" << std::endl;
      arg->SetInt(GRPC_ARG_ALLOW_REUSEPORT, 0);
  }

  void UpdatePlugins(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ServerBuilderPlugin>>* plugins)  GRPC_OVERRIDE
  {
      for(auto s = plugins->begin(); s!= plugins->end(); ++s)
      {
          std::cout << (*s)->name() << std::endl;
      }
  }
};

... 

   std::unique_ptr<ServerBuilderOption> opts(new Opts);
   builder.SetOption(std::move(opts));
```

Comment: Are you using C++? I'd expect that to be a soft failure: you don't get SO_REUSEPORT functionality, but the server still starts and runs. The "Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051" seems to agree with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is C++. And it seems to run, as you said. But the testclient doesn't receive anything, so something fails -- and this is the only output I get.. Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get on the client? I assume you are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:50051 or localhost:50051

Comment: We don't get any error.. it just appears that nothing is happening. In the client code, it is trying to connect to localhost:50051. We tried changing the server code, so that it doesn't use SO_REUSEPORT (see code in next comment)

Comment: class Opts : public ::grpc::ServerBuilderOption
{
public:
void UpdateArguments(ChannelArguments* arg) GRPC_OVERRIDE
{
    std::cout << "UpdateArguments called:" << std::endl;
    arg->SetInt(GRPC_ARG_ALLOW_REUSEPORT, 0);
}

void UpdatePlugins(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ServerBuilderPlugin>>* plugins)  GRPC_OVERRIDE
{
    for(auto s = plugins->begin(); s!= plugins->end(); ++s)
    {
        std::cout << (*s)->name() << std::endl;
    }
}
};

63a102,103
std::unique_ptr<ServerBuilderOption> opts(new Opts);

64a105,106
builder.SetOption(std::move(opts));